# Selenium Python login using Chrome profile

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use a Chrome profile to login to skinport.com.

Here is my code:

"""

```
option = uc.ChromeOptions()

option.add_argument(
     rf'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
option.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default')
option.add_argument("--log-level=3")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=option)

time.sleep(2)

driver.get("https://skinport.com")

time.sleep(3)
```

"""

The program successfully opens a Chrome browser where I am logged into Google, but then I get this error:

"""

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\OneDrive\Desktop\BuffMarket Purchase Bot V3.0\Testing.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=option)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 53, in __new__
    instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 357, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0087DCE3+50899]
    (No symbol) [0x0080E111]
    (No symbol) [0x00715588]
    (No symbol) [0x0073281C]
    (No symbol) [0x0072F479]
    (No symbol) [0x00761FFE]
    (No symbol) [0x00761CEC]
    (No symbol) [0x0075B6F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00737708]
    (No symbol) [0x0073886D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00AE3EAE+2566302]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B192B1+2784417]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B1327C+2759788]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00915740+672048]
    (No symbol) [0x00818872]
    (No symbol) [0x008141C8]
    (No symbol) [0x008142AB]
    (No symbol) [0x008071B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76D97D49+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77B6B74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x77B6B6CF+191]
```

"""

Any idea what could be causing this error? Also, for reference, I navigated to a webpage where my Chrome priofile should have me logged in, but I am not logged in.

Thanks for any help

*UPDATE

I am still getting the same error, but with the following code I can manually navigate to the webpage and I am logged in:

```
exec_path_driver = r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

ch_options = Options()
ch_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\kumpd\\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=exec_path_driver, options=ch_options)

driver.get("https://skinport.com")
```

My problem now is that the error prevents anything following in the program to be prevented from running, so I still very much need to fix it.

Comment: I haven't figured out what causes the problem but it happens to me when I run selenium when there were other previously opened chrome sessions. `Close all chrome browsers windows` before running selenium or alternatively add `--headless` to chrome options

Comment: Try taking off the `\User Data` from `C:\Users\kumpd\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`. I don't have Windows but if I use `option.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/dan/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default")` I get a clean browser session in Ubuntu. If I use `option.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/dan/snap/chromium/common/chromium")` I get my existing session. I can't test it as I don't have a Windows machine

Comment: @Dan-Dev this got rid of the error, but now I am not logged into Chrome when the window opens.

Comment: @Michael From what I understand, headless ensures that the program runs in the background without opening a visible Chrome window. I also tried closing all browser windows and a window does open with me already logged into Google, but driver.get never navigates me to the webpage and the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with this code:

```
ch_options = Options()
ch_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
ch_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\kumpd\\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=ch_options)

time.sleep(2)

driver.get("https://skinport.com/market?cat=Container&item=Glove+Case&sort=price&order=asc")
```

I believe the problem was the exec_driver_path I was using. I was also missing the Service object.